# Why does my email HTML get rendered wrong in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I've created the following HTML email fiddle:
[fiddle HTML email](https://jsfiddle.net/j23nrg1z/)

The layout looks great on `Gmail, Hotmail, and outlook web`, but in `Outlook Client` it looks horrible, as can be seen in the screenshot below:
[image: outlook client mail issue]

I've been looking at this code and changing small stuff for the past few days, and it seems to be impossible to fix this layout.

The original email was built using the following MJML:

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body background-color="#f2f8f9">
    <mj-section background-color="#77c5d5" padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="0">
      <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="100%">
        <mj-image src="https://www.test.com/white-logo.png" alt="logo" align="center" border="none" width="200px" padding-left="0px" padding-right="0px" padding-bottom="10px" padding-top="10px"></mj-image>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
    <mj-section background-color="#FFFFFF" padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="0">
      <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="100%">
        <mj-text align="center" color="#1a5966" font-size="28px" font-weight="bold" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="25px" padding-right="25px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="25px">Nieuwe vrijwilligers vacatures</mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
    <mj-section background-color="#FFFFFF" padding-bottom="20px">
      <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="100%">
        <mj-text align="left" color="#000000" font-size="18px" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="25px" padding-right="25px">
          <span style="color:#000000">Dag John,</span>
        </mj-text>
        <mj-text align="left" color="#000000" font-size="15px" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="25px" padding-right="25px">
          Er zijn enkele vrijwilligersvacatures bij jou in de buurt, die passen bij jouw interesse. 
Bekijk even of het iets voor jou is! Je kan ze ook doorsturen naar vrienden. Het zou echt top zijn als ze geholpen kunnen worden
<br/><br/>
          Je kan je buurten en interesses voor een betere matching steeds veranderen in je profiel.
        </mj-text>
        <mj-button align="center" href="https://www.google.be" font-size="18px" font-weight="bold" background-color="#77c5d5" border="2px solid #D9E9EB;" color="#ffffff" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Zoek vrijwilligerswerk!</mj-button>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
    
  <mj-section background-color="#FFFFFF">
    <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="100%">
        <mj-divider border-width="2px" border-style="solid" border-color="lightgrey"></mj-divider>
        <mj-text align="center" color="#1a5966" font-size="28px" font-weight="bold" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="25px" padding-right="25px" padding-bottom="15px" padding-top="15px">Nieuwe vacatures gevonden voor jou</mj-text>
        <mj-divider border-width="2px" border-style="solid" border-color="lightgrey"></mj-divider>
    </mj-column>
    <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="50%">
      <mj-image height="125px"src="https://test.com/vacancies/2568/banner-picture_1900.webp"></mj-image>
    </mj-column>
    <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="50%">
      <mj-button href="https://www.test.be/" font-size="17px" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" background-color="transparent" color="#1a5966" text-align="left" align="left" width="100%" padding="0">
          Dag- of nachtoppas in BREE
      </mj-button>
      <mj-text padding-bottom="0">Antwerpen (2000)</mj-text>
      <mj-text padding-bottom="0">Begeleiding</mj-text>
      <mj-text padding-top="0" padding-bottom="0">Educatie</mj-text>
      <mj-text padding-top="0">Jongeren</mj-text>
    </mj-column>
    <mj-column width="100%">
        <mj-divider border-width="2px" border-style="solid" border-color="lightgrey"></mj-divider>
    </mj-column>
      <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="50%">
        <mj-image height="125px"src="https://test.com/vacancies/2568/banner-picture_1900.webp"></mj-image>
      </mj-column>
      <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="50%">
        <mj-button href="https://www.test.be/" font-size="17px" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" background-color="transparent" color="#1a5966" text-align="left" align="left" width="100%" padding="0">
          Vrijwilliger voor administratieve hulp aan huis
         </mj-button>
        <mj-text padding-bottom="0">Antwerpen (2000)</mj-text>
        <mj-text padding-bottom="0">Begeleiding</mj-text>
        <mj-text padding-top="0" padding-bottom="0">Educatie</mj-text>
        <mj-text padding-top="0">Jongeren</mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="100%">
        <mj-divider border-width="2px" border-style="solid" border-color="lightgrey"></mj-divider>
        <mj-text align="center" color="#1a5966" font-size="28px" font-weight="bold" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="25px" padding-right="25px" padding-bottom="15px" padding-top="15px">Andere interessante vacatures</mj-text>
    </mj-column>
    <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="50%">
      <mj-image height="125px"src="https://test.com/vacancies/13333/banner-picture_1900.webp"></mj-image>
    </mj-column>
    <mj-column vertical-align="top" width="50%">
      <mj-button href="https://www.test.be/" font-size="17px" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" background-color="transparent" color="#1a5966" text-align="left" align="left" width="100%" padding="0">
          CALM pour une cohabitation interculturelle
      </mj-button>
      <mj-text padding-bottom="0">Brussel (1000)</mj-text>
      <mj-text padding-bottom="0">Begeleiding</mj-text>
      <mj-text padding-top="0" padding-bottom="0">Educatie</mj-text>
      <mj-text padding-top="0">Jongeren</mj-text>
    </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
    <mj-section padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="0">
      <mj-column width="100%">
        <mj-image src="https://www.test.be/design/img/email-footer-no-clouds.png" alt="footer"></mj-image>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
    <mj-section padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="0">
      <mj-column vertical-align="middle" width="100%">
        <mj-social font-size="14px" icon-size="25px" mode="horizontal">
          <mj-social-element name="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/test.be"></mj-social-element>
          <mj-social-element name="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/test.be/"></mj-social-element>
          <mj-social-element  name="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/test"></mj-social-element>
        </mj-social>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text align="center" font-size="10px" padding-top="0">Copyright 2021 - test. Alle rechten voorbehouden.</mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

Comment: If you check the output on MJML live editor, it gives you the final code, e.g. https://mjml.io/try-it-live/OT-XRXdBSF_ and I noticed that it is not ending the Outlook conditional rows properly. If you add in the next rows (`</tr><tr>`) in the correct spots, it fixes it. But not sure if this is a problem with MJML or your code.

Answer (score 0):

MJML documentation includes, "The sum of columns in a section cannot be greater than the width of the parent `mj-section` (or 100%)." Maybe you have this in a couple places. That'll make it better!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier. There are lots of MJMLers on [MJML Slack](https://mjml.slack.com/), generally daily. Give them a try, too!

Comment: New signup link for https://mjml.slack.com:  (signup: https://join.slack.com/t/mjml/shared_invite/zt-gqmwfwmr-kPBnfuuB7wof5httaTcXxg)